# How to convert byte data to readable text in Java

Tags: java, spring

I'm new to java and need some understanding on below.

```
private static void decompressGzipFile(String gzipFile, String newFile) {
           try {
               FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(gzipFile);
               GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(fis);
               FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
               byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
               int len;
               while((len = gis.read(buffer)) != -1){
                   fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
               }
               //close resources
               System.out.println("Decompression is successful");
               fos.close();
               gis.close();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
```

I have some data in compressed GZIP file which is in

```
í?]o£F ?s?_1RoZ?Öó?¹Ã?d¬ÅÆ[1]?U.?¦Q?8²?Dù÷=?íÄÃÌ ?VUUÎM´d Î?÷|Ì?Í?7ÉöaõÇjûzö³ 
?9 ??Á¤?? ?? fs?c?;î&amp;Äq?3?Ú?&gt;ÙËv·Ü t¶Y¯w¦uM¿ÿ?Z²?Æò?
________________________________________
[hº~Biþ?F
________________________________________

ÎÁ?bâ??OÃÙ[1]Yã0ó'Q?¬?x?¡ ?â
```

This is byte data and how can I convert this to string format or readable format in java? 
I tried using GZip Uncompressor to read this file but that give me the same file as output but I want the data to be in human readable format. I tried using GZIPInputStream and base64inputStream but that gives incorrect data type. I'm not sure if this is really byte data or how to read this data? any suggestions please help

Comment: Before doing `fos.write(buffer, 0, len);` debug it by writing the `buffer` as a String to stdout.

Comment: What kind of file are you decompressing?  What is its filename?

Comment: file name is gzipFile, I'm trying to decompress .gz file.

Comment: @ScaryWombat, I tried to debug using buffer reader but it still shows the same format in the variable field like - í?]o£F ?s?_1RoZ?Öó?¹Ã?d¬ÅÆ[1]?U.?¦Q?8²?Dù÷=?íÄÃÌ ?VUUÎM´d Î?÷|Ì?Í?7ÉöaõÇjûzö³

Comment: OK, so it looks like a compression issue.  Please show how you are compressing.

Answer (score 1):

FileOutputStream bydefault writes data into files using encoding.

If you want to skip encoding , use BufferedReader

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.FileInputStream;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStreamReader;
   import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;


    public class ZipFileReader{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        GZIPInputStream zipFile = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:/Users/HimanshuSharma2/Downloads/phayes-geoPHP-1.2-20-g6855624.tar.gz"));

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(zipFile));
        String content;

        while ((content = br.readLine()) != null)
           System.out.println(content);
    }
    }
```

checked on sample file from this link: https://github.com/phayes/geoPHP/tarball/master

and finally write this string into file.

Comment: I still get byte data which is not decoded into string

Comment: As I think your gzip file is already having encrypted data then it is not decompression issue it is encryption/encoding issue. Use the same algo to decode the string that you are generating.